# WebApps override my custom shortcuts

Tags: macos, keyboard, google-chrome, web-app

I am having some issues when trying to use my PC keyboard on my Mac. I decided to get back my keyboard because it is too uncomfortable to use the typical <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>X</kbd>/<kbd>V</kbd>/<kbd>Z</kbd>/<kbd>F</kbd> commands.

What I did is to map in **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **App Shortcuts** the "All Applications" those shortcuts and in most of the applications they work well, but somehow not in Google Chrome. Inside the context of Google Chrome as an application, they work well (for example, in the Settings menu) but when you have a focused webpage, they don't. I suspect the web application overrides this and listens only to the "traditional" Mac shortcuts but I have no clue on how to tell Chrome to avoid this.

This is a big issue because I work a lot in Google Docs and not having my shortcuts workings is painful. Here is a screenshot of my settings.

[image: Screenshot of the Keyboard Preferences Pane]

Can I configure chrome to not gobble up the key shortcuts the OS should process for Google docs and sheets web applications?