# Modifiers key does not work

Tags: mac, keyboard

This is something that is starting to get in my nerves. Basically I am mapping the Command key to Control key, it is being stressful for me to try the typical combinations (Copy/Cut/Paste) with Command. This menu in settings looks pretty straightforward to change this behaviour but it does not work at all.

[image]

Would I need to set up another configuration?

---

macOS Monterey Version 12.4

Comment: So with this mapping, if you press Cmd+C on the keyboard, it gets interpreted as Ctrl+C by the OS. That does not trigger the copy menu item. Don't you want to map pressing the Control key to act like the Command key?

Comment: This setup, combined with your [previously changing all defaults to Ctrl](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/442541/85275), is just going to mess with your head far more than simply learning how it's supposed to work. You're making life difficult for yourself, no wonder it's getting annoying. *Vive la Difference.*

Comment: DarkDust, thanks, I was interpreting this in a bad way. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You've got the assignment reversed. You want to assign the Control key (which you keep hitting) to the Command function. The way you have it, no key does the Command function, which makes it impossible for you to do cut/copy/paste via keyboard.

Be careful with this. Depending on your usage, this could create unintended consequences. Command and Control usage aren't simply reversed on Mac compared to PC.